# OS appears as Unknown on Selenium Grid Hub console when Node Platform is configured as LINUX through selenium grid

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I am using windows7 and trying to run my test cases on LINUX by setting the platform. I am specifying the browser properties in node.json as below:

```
{
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "maxInstances": 2,
    "platform":"LINUX",
    "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
}
```

But, in the browser when I open the Hub url console, the result is like this.
[to see result click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siCsF.png)

Here, my question is: Should we have LINUX OS to the node to say run with LINUX platform? Can anyone help me on this issue??

Answer (score 0):

As per the [WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) in chapter [7. Capabilities](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#processing-capabilities#x7-capabilities), section [7.2 Processing Capabilities](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#processing-capabilities#x7-2-processing-capabilities) there is no **capability** as **`platform`**. The supported **capability** is **`platformName`** and the supported values are:

- `linux`
- `mac`
- `windows`

**Note**: This list is not exhaustive. When returning capabilities from New Session, it is valid to return a more specific platformName, allowing users to correctly identify the Operating System the WebDriver implementation is running on.

### Solution

Change the **capabilities** in *node.json* as:

```
{
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "maxInstances": 2,
    "platformName":"linux",
    "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I can see that, the change in the property name. But, still facing the same issue as unknown and I am using Grid Console v3.12.0. Does windows7 supports to run on LINUX platform?